# bootstrap drop down button on click to execute action

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url_for('account.order_complete', order_id=order.id) }}">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> 
        Confirm Delivery
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="{{ url_for('account.order_dispute', order_id=order.id) }}">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i> 
                Open Dispute
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On click I need go on link `{{ url_for('account.order_complete', order_id=order.id) }}` to return normal url, but on click of the button to not execute anything, where is the problem?

Comment: What's `{{ url_for('account.order_dispute', order_id=order.id) }}`? in what language is that?

Comment: Did you add the jQuery `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with below code

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
<a name="order_comp" id="order_comp" class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ url_for('account.order_complete', order_id=order.id) }}">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i> 
    Confirm Delivery
</a>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url_for('account.order_dispute', order_id=order.id) }}">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></i> 
            Open Dispute
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```